# Django Dynamic Choices in Form that persist

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, python-3.x, django-1.7

What I need to know how to do is reload the models module. I need to automate restarting the server `manage.py runserver` or whatever it does to reload the models. OR, I need to know a better way to do dynamic options. However, what I have here is working, the only problem is that I have to restart `manage.py runserver` the server for the choices to reload into the model. All the examples using imp.reload are NOT working. Here is everything in more depth:

I am trying to find the best way to implement a model field using [MultiSelectField](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-multiselectfield) that allows for dynamic choices entered by the user on the front end. The choices will look like they do in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JeremyCraigMartinez/z5fv6agc/3/).

```
<div class="row ">
<ul id="id_field">

  <div class="col-lg-6" style="width:100%;">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">
        <label for="id_field_0">
          <input id="id_field_0" type="checkbox" aria-label="..." name="field_0" value="0">
        </label>
      </span>
      <label type="text" class="form-control" style="height: auto; !important;" aria-label="..." >option 0</label>
    </div><!-- /input-group -->
  </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->

  ...

  <div class="col-lg-6" style="width:100%;">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">
        <label for="id_field_4">
          <input id="id_field_4" type="checkbox" aria-label="..." name="field_4" value="4">
        </label>
      </span>
      <label type="text" class="form-control" style="height: auto; !important;" aria-label="..." >option 4</label>
    </div><!-- /input-group -->
  </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->

</ul>
</div><!-- /.row -->  
Enter new option: <input></input>
```

I would like to use jQuery to send an ajax request by submitting a new option. Then the django app would save an option in a model in my home app here:

So the model questions is updated pretty much every time I restart the server because it pulls its options from another model. This is all a bit of a hack, but there doesn't seem to be a very clean distinct way to do this (that I've seen for Django 1.7 / Python 3.4). I have been reading that I might be able to reload the model module with imp.reload, however, this doesn't seem to be working. Any ideas?

EDIT:

models.py:

```
class garbage_choices(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class model_with_dynamic_choices(models.Model):
    garbage = models.ManyToManyField(garbage_choices)
```

views.py:

```
if request.POST:
    if context['model_with_dynamic_choices'].is_valid():
        tmp = context[form].save(commit=False)
        # somehow add all the choices from the html form???
        tmp.save()
        tmp.save_m2m
```

Answer (score 0):

You are try to manage a relationship between one thing, and things which can dynamically change. The best way it to just model this using Django models and store it in the database:

```
class MyDynamicChoices(models.Model):
    value = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class questions(models.Model):
    field_1 = ForeignKey(MyDynamicChoices)
```

If you need to model multiple choices, then use a [`ManyToManyField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/):

```
class MyDynamicChoices(models.Model):
    value = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class questions(models.Model):
    field_1 = ManyToManyField(MyDynamicChoices)
```

No need to restart the server, all validation is taken care of using the database and models.

Comment: How does this solve the issues of having multiple choices for one field?

Comment: I didn't see that requirement, in that case just use a `ManyToManyField`

Comment: I think that could work, but it gets a little messy when I try to save anything. The documentation on [django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/) is pretty awful at explaining how to save multiple m2m's to one model

Comment: If you can fix your model and field names, so they are more descriptive I might be able to give a better answer. `question` and `field_1` aren't very informative about what you are *actually* trying to achieve.

Comment: There, I edited so the bottom models and views look similar to how the models are setup and how I want to save it. I'm just using the id of the ```garbage_choices``` model instead of value like in your answer

Comment: Thats not what I meant, what I meant is you are storing something in `field_1`, ***what is `field_1` actually modelling?***

Comment: nothing anymore. It was representing another model completely where I stored the options. _Now_ I have completely scrapped that and am using ManyToManyField instead. ```garbage_choices``` is in place of ```field_1``` now. It represents all the choices that you see in the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JeremyCraigMartinez/z5fv6agc/3/)